# Can you mask an SKSpriteNode with another SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, mask, skspritenode, skcropnode

Just ask the title asks, I am wondering if this is at all possible. Most examples of the SKCropNode use a texture or a shape. What I want to accomplish is a mask of a custom shape. Let me know if there's a way!

Comment: What is an SKMaskNode? Do you mean SKCropNode?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean to say, my apologies. Edited.

Comment: ok,  you can use any SKNode as your mask,  whatever your final results of your mask are,  if the alpha < .5 it is cropped (Unless it is another crop node,  then you get alpha level cropping, which is handy)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon could you kindly elaborate on what you mean by alpha level cropping?

Comment: @Crashalot Alpha level cropping means your pixel will only drop to the alpha level of the mask, so if you have a solid white image, and use alpha masking of 75%, then your white image becomes 25% transparent

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could mask a node by giving it a child node where the child node's zPosition is greater than the parent's. And then, of course, you'd have to position the child node correctly on top of the parent node -but this should be easy as the child node's position is located relative to the parent node (i.e. if parent has position (25, 30) in the scene, and you set child.position = CGPoint(x:5, y:0), the child's position in the scene would be (30, 30)). Also, if the parent node moves, the child node moves with it.

Comment: This is not a mask,  this is an overlay.  Masks in this case is data used for bitwise operations. E.G. SKCropNodes,  any pixel with alpha < 0.5 in a mask is cropped on the given node

Comment: Yes I wish to use a mask using the SKCropNode, not placing a node on top of another.